# is there any Netbeans or Eclipse C++ portable with mingw include?

Tags: c++, netbeans, portable-applications

Im looking for Netbeans or Eclipse Portable version with C++ plugin and MinGW already integrate, i want to have this on a pendrive, and not to have to setup anything but i dont have any problem if the only setting i make is add the PATH of MinGW on the Enviroment settings on windows

I was looking on the internet but i didn't found any solution, i dont want to use "Code Blocks" or DevCpp

I had a very good experience before with Netbeans + MinGW , so this is my first option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t is more natural in Eclipse to set the tool chain. However, you can try for example **Wascana**.

Comment: is what i was looking for :D is a shame that the project has been discontinued https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/wascana/ , but it works for me even in that version